# How many simultaineous oil drilling rig explosions needed for apocolypse?

Tags: science-based, apocalypse

How many deep sea oil rigs (like the Deepwater Horizon) would have to explode simultaineously in each ocean around the world to overwhelm emergency response teams' ability to contain the disasters and cause irreparable damage, ultimately leading to the end of the world as we know it? You can also include non-deep-sea rigs. You can include existing offshore oil rigs and also any rigs that could plausibly be built in the near-future (100 years).

Comment: What do you consider to be "overwhelming society"? I suspect most people don't particularly care about the Deepwater Horizon disaster and many aren't aware that it happened at all.

Comment: @Frostfyre I mean overwhelming emergency response teams' ability to contain the disasters before it results in an end of the world scenario, either directly or indirectly (indirectly meaning long-term ecological damage, etc)

Comment: This is essentially the same question you already asked about Deepwater Horizon.  The simple fact of the matter is that all oil spills are local disasters.  Big disasters, but localized.  Even if every wellhead in the ocean exploded, those disasters would mostly impact the local environment, not the globe. We overestimate our impacts on the environment. News makes things look bigger and more disastrous than they are.  And most oil productions zones contain life forms that thrive on hydrocarbons and do most of the long term cleanup.

Comment: @ZoeyBoles Can you put this in an answer so it can be voted on? Or should I do it?

Comment: It would send oil prices through the roof and many people would stop driving, but seeing as a lot of gas also comes from oil rigs, a lot of people would loose heating, power, and seeing as many household products rely on oil in at least one stage of manufacture, everything from toothbrushes to some pharmaceuticals would suddenly become very hard to get. Would the destruction of all the worlds oil rigs result in an apocalypse? Quite likely. But because of overwhelmed emergency forces? Environmental damage? No.

Answer (score 0):

Opinion (since I haven't run the numbers): Even if all the offshore oil wells in the Carribean were destroyed simultaneously and 'just right' to make them effectively irreparable, that would not cause a global apocalypse nor anything close.  Terrible regional damage, yes.

Fishing and shrimping in the entire Caribbean would probably be officially off limits and perhaps thousands of miles of coast would have major oil damage and repair costs, possibly for decades.  But that's a regional disaster, not the end of the world.  A thousand miles away, it would barely register on most people, other than slight price changes to fish and shrimp.  And most people on the planet are farther away than that.  I'm not trying to trivialize oil spills or the damage they can do, but this wouldn't cause mass deaths (beyond those on those rigs) or end 'life as we know it.'

Comment: Ok, so what if rigs from all across the globe were involved? How many per ocean would be required?